# Create Chromium's WebView and place it on a Form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Since turns out the current WebBrowser for Android offering not sufficient for my project properties - I need to create a native instance of Chromium WebView and place it on my Delphi's forms, yet I am unable to find anything similar as an example.

- How to create a native Chromium's WebView and place it on my Delphi's Forms ?

Comment: There is no Delphi XE11. The last Delphi with "XE" in its name was ``Delphi XE8``!

Comment: Correct! Thank You fellow for noticing it.

Comment: And you didn't even [query a search here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi+chromium)? What's your actual problem?

Comment: TChromium is Windows only. It is not Android as far as I know. Can You point me to the Android implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it all by yourself – it’s a lot of work. Better to use free components to do it. You can check https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi project. There are a lot of demo and you can choose the best way to solve your task. There is VCL version for Windows and FMX version for multiplatform.

Comment: CEF4Delphi does not support android.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We have made corrections to our response.

Comment: this is not applicable to Android. It is using completely different and not applicable to Android approach.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works with Windows, Linux and macOS, but not for Android. Didn't notice that you are asking specifically about Android